# Java regex replaceAll with boundaries not working

Tags: java, regex

```
    System.out.println("R.A.F. stands for R.A.F. blablabla".replaceAll(
            "\\bR\\.A\\.F\\.\\b", "royal airforce army"));
```

I want to replace the second R.A.F in the string with "royal airforce army", why isn't it working?

Comment: Why do you use `\\b` before and after? I'd try it without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word boundary matches any point where:

- the previous character is a word character and the next character is not (or the end of the string)
  *or*
- the next character is a word character and the previous character is not (or the beginning of the string).

Since `.` is not a word character, the pattern `\.\b`, will only match a `.` which is followed by a word character, i.e. it will match `R.A.F.foo`, but not `R.A.F. foo`.

If you want to ensure that it doesn't match `R.A.F.` which is immediately followed by a word character, use this instead:

```
"\\bR\\.A\\.F\\.(?!\\w)"
```

But this will replace both instances in your sample input, since the first `R.A.F` is preceeded by the beginning of the string. If you just want to replace the second one, I'd suggest using something like this:

```
"(?<=\\W)R\\.A\\.F\\.(?!\\w)"
```

Comment: That will replace both occurences of `R.A.F.`. I would use `System.out.println("R.A.F. stands for R.A.F. blablabla".replaceAll("(?<=\\s)R\\.A\\.F\\.", "royal airforce army"));`

Comment: It was still a good answer for what I actually needed it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

```
System.out.println("R.A.F. stands for R.A.F. blablabla".replaceAll(
                   "\\sR\\.A\\.F\\.", " royal airforce army"));
```

**Output:**

```
R.A.F. stands for royal airforce army blablabla
```

**PS:**
Note I added an space before "royal airforce army".